# Can't view Visual Web Developer Websites when copy to web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-web-developer

As far as I can work out I should be able to copy a web project/application to my IIS Web server and be able to see it as I do when designing it on my development computer.

The problem is once I copy the folder over to my web server and then try to view it the browser it says Error 404 not found. There must be a real simple fix for this. I would like to be able to develop ASP.NET sites using the Visual Web Developer instead of Dreamweaver but this little issue is stopping me. Any ideas?

Cheers,

Darren Woolway

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy over the files and expect it to run. You have to do a little more work than this.

please see the following;

non iis7: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972

iis7: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/37/deploying-web-sites-on-iis-7/

Comment: I know how to do this as I have already set it up as a test server for my other work I do with asp.net in Dreamweaver. All I would usually need to do is type in the server name, followed by the folder, and then the page name to be able to view it e.g.

http://ehc-32-dgw/ecoshools/default.aspx 

then when I am happy I copy the files onto my main server with the webdomain to make it live so it becomes: http://www.elthamhill.greenwich.sch.uk/eco_school.aspx

However this does not work when using a project I created in Visual Web Developer.

Comment: Oh ok. I have seen this issue many times before and each time it was the permissions on the folders / user account of the (live) web server. Perhaps someone else may be able to assist you further. Good luck :)